# Crosscompiled c# socket program, works on win, but not on mac

Tags: c#, node.js, sockets, tcp

I have a socket program which crosscompiles between win and mac. It does many different things, but its essentially a socket server that recieves commands from different types of clients.

Clients are written in NodeJs, c++.

The NodeJS client is running the same code on windows and mac, and works on both platforms,  except for the socket connection.

The C# socket server looks like this, stripped of exceptionhandling.

```
.
.
.

IPHostEntry ipHost = Dns.GetHostEntry("localhost");
IPAddress ipAddr = ipHost.AddressList[0];
IPEndPoint LocalEndPoint = new(ipAddr, 11111);
Socket listener = new(ipAddr.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
listener.Bind(LocalEndPoint);
listener.Listen(10);
while (true){
  Socket serverSocket = listener.Accept();
  byte[] recievedBytes = new byte[1024];
  string data;
  while (true){
    data=null;
    int numByte = serverSocket.Recieve(recievedBytes);
    data += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(recievedBytes, 0, numByte);
    ClientMessageDTO cMessage = new();
    cMessage = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ClientMessageDTO>(data);
    string jsonMessage = executeSocketCommand.now(cMessage, list);
    sendMessage(serverSocket, jsonMessage);
    serverSocket.Disconnect(true);
    serverSocket.listener.Accept();
  }
}
.
.
.
```

The NodeJS code looks like this, stripped of exception handling.

```
.
.
.
const net = require("net");
const socket = new net.Socket();
socket.connect (11111, "localhost");
socket.write("{\"command\":\"updateLicenseRelationshipList\",\"value\":\"\"", 
  socket.destroy();
});

.
.
.
```

On Windows it works, but on mac the client cannot connect to the server. It simply does not see it.

I've tried to not start the server at all on Mac, and get the same "Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:11111 at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect as oncolplete (net.js:1146:16)

I've looked for differences in how Mac and Win handles localhost on the internet but cant seem to find it. TCP is standard and needs to be handled as a standard, but eventhough i think thats were the problem lies, and therefor tried 127.0.0.1 but that does not work either.

The Server works fine. I've writte a c# socket test program which connects to the server and it works on both Win and Mac and can send and recieve messages.

Does anyone have any idea of what this problem is, and point me in the right direction.

Thankyou for your time.

Comment: TCP is standard. And it's a *stream of bytes*, not *messages*. So if you want to make sure that what you're dealing with, say, an entire JSON document (and not part of one, nor parts of multiple ones), it's up to *you* to slice and dice the received bytes until you can assemble one (by here, for example, you'd probably have to balance `{` and `}` until you hit a count of 0).

Comment: Thankyou for your answer, but the code does not even get to send anything. Ive removed all the comms code, and only tried to connect, and it wont work.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the answer to the problem, but im not sure... It works though.

127.0.0.1 and localhost is the same, and is the loopback ipaddress on all machines which makes processes able to communicate via a TCP v4 connection. Traffic sent to this address cannot be read in any other address range. But for it to work localhost and 127.0.0.1 needs to be in a host file for dns resolution. If it is not it will not work.

0.0.0.0 on the other hand is available in all address ranges and can be listened to from the addressrange of the host computer given to it by a dhcp server. It needs no dns resolution.

I dunno if this is the answer, but when i communicated on 0.0.0.0 it worked on both Win and MacOS.